# Good Practices for updating camera matrix

Tags: opengl, camera

I'm learning OpenGL right now, specifically how to move a camera. If I wish to change my camera matrix, for example, if the user is translating it with WASD, there are two primary ways I could do this:

1. Pre-multiply the camera matrix by the new translation matrix.
2. Manage a set of attributes for the camera, such as position, viewing angle, up-vector, modify those, and re-compute the camera matrix from these.

Which of these is considered better? I feel like the first would introduce drift, and the second would require more computation, but I don't know enough to analyze the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest way to model camera is to use 'lookAt' system. Basically you remember `camera_pos`, `camera_target`, optionally `camera_up` vectors. Then you build final matrix using old `gluLookAt` or some modern way like `glm::lookAt`.

That way it is easier to model camera and its parameters.

here are some links:

- http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84698/OpenGL-Camera
- http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html

Do not look that much at the performance cost. First learn something, build it... then optimize if needed.

Comment: Yeah, it does fall under 'premature optimization', but since I'll end up doing this frequently, and so many people have done it before, I figured it'd make sense to ask early. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: 'premature optimization' is not only your problem :)

Comment: Don't spend too much time worrying about the computation time. Make it work and optimize if needed. I highly doubt that it will become a problem as long as you don't start recomputing it ten thousands of times per frame. Compute it once.. and pass it to your shader.